# Ошибка с xutility

Tags: c++

пытаясь создать функцию которая бы выдавала случайное простое число, я получаю следующие ошибки при компиляции:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2065   '_Ty1': undeclared identifier   Project4    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility  3931
>   Warning   C4244   'argument': conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int',
>   possible loss of data Project4    c:\users\andrii\documents\visual studio
>   2017\projects\project4\project4\source.cpp    8    Error  C2825   '_Urng':
>   must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    Project4    c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility  3929
>   Error C2510   '_Urng': left of '::' must be a
>   class/struct/union    Project4    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility  3929
>   Error C2061   syntax error: identifier 'result_type'  Project4    c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility  3929
>   Error C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   Project4    c:\program
>   files (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility  3929
>   Error C2065   '_Ty1': undeclared identifier   Project4    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility  3931
>   Error C2923   'std::conditional_t': '_Ty1' is not a valid template type
>   argument for parameter '_Ty2' Project4    c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual
>   studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.12.25827\include\xutility  3931

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

int GetRandomNumber(std::size_t f = 300, std::size_t d = 1000)
{
    static std::default_random_engine dre(std::time(nullptr));
    return std::uniform_int_distribution<>()(f, d);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << GetRandomNumber() << std::endl;
    return 0;
    system("pause");

}
```

Буду очень благодарен всем, кто объяснит мне мои ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аргументами конструктора для `distribution` являются числа, задающие диапазон (которые в данном случае должны быть `int` а не `size_t`), а аргументом оператора () - генератор (который у вас не задействуется никак). Должно быть так:

```
return std::uniform_int_distribution<>{f, d}(dre);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь